# Why is the value of state inside click handler not updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React Hooks and could not figure out why the state value inside an `onclick` handler is not updating and gives the initial state value. But it can be normally accessed inside the function.
I need to access the state variable `NewGrid` inside the onclick handler `clicked`.

Code snippet:

```
const Grid = () => {
  const [NewGrid, setGrid] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    MakeGrid();
  }, []);

  const MakeGrid = () => {
    let grid = <div onClick={(e) => clicked(e)}>CLICK ME!</div>;
    setGrid(grid);
  };
  console.log("From main Grid", NewGrid);
  const clicked = (e) => {
    // Error -> Why value of state is not updated inside the click handler
    console.log(`Click Handler: State: ${JSON.stringify(NewGrid)}`);
  };
  return <div className="grid">{NewGrid}</div>;
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Grid />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox Link to replicate the error](https://codesandbox.io/s/onclick-handler-e9wgo)

Comment: Please show the relevant code in question. Questions should be self contained enough that we shouldn't need to go off site just to review the initial problem. Demos are great but only as support for what actually exists in the question itself.

Comment: Added code snippet. @charlietfl

Comment: Start by explaining what you are expecting this to do. You are not calling setGrid() in the `clicked()` function. Not entirely clear what you are wanting to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

The particular problem occurs because your `MakeGrid` function is only called once. Because your deps is empty array. So it captures the very first version on `clicked` function that in turn captures initial value of `NewGrid` state.

Since I don't know your requirements and what you are trying to achieve I can only propose you to use ref to store actual value of `clicked` handler. Though this is somewhat convoluted approach and I do recommend you to rethink the very idea of storing react nodes in state.

[Demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/onclick-handler-forked-w1mkn?file=/src/App.js:84-699)

```
const Grid = () => {
  const [NewGrid, setGrid] = useState();
  const clickedRef = useRef(); // declare mutable reference
  useEffect(() => {
    MakeGrid();
  }, []);

  const MakeGrid = () => {
    console.log("From make grid");
    // let grid = new Array(rows);
    let grid = <div onClick={(e) => clickedRef.current(e)}>CLICK ME!</div>;
    setGrid(grid);
  };
  console.log("From main Grid", NewGrid);
  // update the ref on every render.
  clickedRef.current = (e) => {
    // Error -> Why value of state is not updated inside the click handler
    console.log(`From Click Handler: State: ${JSON.stringify(NewGrid)}`);
  };
  return <div className="grid">{NewGrid}</div>;
};
```

Comment: You mean that since `MakeGrid` is called once, the onclick handler gets the initial value of the state and not the new state since it is not called again?

Comment: Yes. And it will always effectively have previous state captured in closure.

Comment: I want to initialize a grid of divs with an onclick inside each of them. The onclick handler when clicked make the specific div change the color.. this is for a pathfinding project.

Comment: I still don't see why would you need effects and all the machinery of storing elements in state. Just store a 2-d array of grid items each having a flag (clicked) and use 2 maps to produce divs from this data. onClick handler will capture which item it should update. So you can craft proper state update function.

Comment: I am storting the 2-D grid in the state and in a loop insert divs with the onclick handler, when clicked it changes the grid to change the color of the specific grid. I am not able to use the state grid inside the `onclick` handler.

Comment: Then we probably have [The XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. :) Also by 2-D grid in state I mean storing POJOs not react elements. `[[{ clicked: false}, { clicked: true}]]` etc.

Comment: Goes back to what I asked originally about exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish because this definitely is an XY problem. Storing data in state, not elements, is definitely what you want

Comment: @YuryTarabanko You are right. We have XY problem here. Sorry for this. I want to create a grid for a pathfinding visualizer project using `react-hooks`. Much like this: https://clementmihailescu.github.io/Pathfinding-Visualizer/. When I click a node it should turn into a wall.